# fatal error: 'google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.h' file not found

Tags: import, terminal, protocol-buffers, homebrew, protoc

I'm compiling a Google protobuf plugin from [these sources](https://github.com/eugeneego/protobuf-objc-arc).

I've installed [protobuf@2.5](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/protobuf@2.5) with the homebrew command:

> brew install protobuf@2.5

After installation I get the following error when trying to compile by calling `make`:

```
Richards-Mac-mini:protobuf-objc-arc richard$ make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in src/compiler
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..     -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.cc
main.cc:17:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.h' file not found
#include <google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

In particular, this line is interesting:

> fatal error: 'google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.h' file not found

While I definitely able to go to this path and find the `plugin.h` file:

> /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf@2.5/2.5.0/include/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.h

[image: screenshot]

Looks, like the library is not linked correctly with the binary and the issue is somehow related to the correct path.

When I try to issue a command `which protoc`, I get:

> /usr/local/opt/protobuf@2.5/bin/protoc

`protoc --version` leads to the following output, which is expected.

> libprotoc 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed by issuing the following commands:**

> brew link --force --overwrite protobuf250

**Output:**

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf@2.5/2.5.0... 14 symlinks created

If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/protobuf@2.5/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

**And then:**

> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/protobuf@2.5/bin:$PATH"' >>
>   ~/.bash_profile

After successful linking I was able to compile the Objective-C plugin without errors.